# Is it possible to have SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege in standard user token (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

In my program, I would like to create a shared memory that could be accessed from any sessions (with `global\` prefix). Also, it should work in standard user token.

So far, the `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` API is failing with `Error 1300`(*Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller*).

So I just wonder about the possibility of having `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege`  in standard user token.

Could you please help?

Comment: Did you check the group policies? There is one that defines who might create global objects.

Comment: Yes. My user account has admin privilege and it is added against SeCreateGlobalPrivilege in policy. The highlight is that I am running app in default UAC without elevation. FYI.

Comment: [mcve] please and I'll consider testing it on my machine.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to make UAC leave any of the administrator privileges in the restricted token.  You only get the five privileges that are normally granted to all users.  You haven't provided us with much context, but in most cases the proper solution for this class of problem is to move the parts of the application that require admin privilege into a system service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At [Microsoft Windows Security](http://securityinternals.blogspot.in/2014/02/windows-protected-administrative.html) blog, it is mentioned that, the following privileges **are only assigned to the elevated token**.

- SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
- SeSecurityPrivilege
- SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
- SeLoadDriverPrivilege
- SeSystemProfilePrivilege
- SeSystemtimePrivilege
- SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege
- SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege
- SeCreatePagefilePrivilege
- SeBackupPrivilege
- SeRestorePrivilege
- SeDebugPrivilege
- SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
- SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege
- SeManageVolumePrivilege
- SeImpersonatePrivilege
- SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
- SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
- SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege

So in standard token, there is no scope for using `AdjustTokenPrivileges` on any of the above privileges.